# Implement custom stream

Tags: c#, stream

I am calling a dll that writes to a stream. The signature of the method in the dll looks like:

```
public bool SomeMethod(Stream stream);
```

and that method will basically write binary data to that stream. So if I will call that method as:

```
var file = System.IO.File.Create("SomeFile.txt");
/* call dll method */ SomeMethod(file);
```

then I will be basically writing the output to that file. In this question I am writing the output to a networkStream.

**Anyways so back to the question**. The reason why I will like to create my own stream is because I will like to know when some events take place. For example if I where to create my own stream class as:

```
class MyStream : Stream
{
    private long Position;

    public override int Read(byte[] buffer, int offset, int count)
    {

            // implementation goes here

            /* HERE I COULD CALL A CUSTOM EVENT */
    }

    public override long Seek(long offset, SeekOrigin origin)
    {
        // SAME THING I WILL LIKE TO PERFORM AN ACTION IF THIS METHOD IS CALLED!
    }

    // etc implement rest of abstract methods....
```

I am writing the output of that stream to the network so I might want to slow down if some event occurs. If I where to have control of the dll then I would not be trying to implement this.

I will appreciate if someone could show me a very basic example of how to implement the abstract methods of the abstract Stream Class.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

The easiest custom stream a stream that "wraps" some other stream (similar to compression streams). Each method would simply redirect its implementation to internal stream.

```
class MyStream : Stream
{
 Stream inner;
 public MyStream(Stream inner)
 {
  this.inner = inner;
 }

 public override int Read(byte[] buffer, int offset, int count) 
 { 
    var result = inner.Read(buffer, offset, count);

            /* HERE I COULD CALL A CUSTOM EVENT */ 
   return result;
 } 
///
}
```

Usage sample: `functionThatTakesStream(new MyStream(new MemoryStream());`.

Real code will need to handle exceptions in operations on inners stream before/after fireing events and deal with IDisposable correctly.

Comment: Such 'wrapper' is an implementation of the Decorator design pattern.

Answer (score 1):

If all you want to do is fire an event when Read, Seek or similar methods are called, override the base class versions, call them directly and raise the appropriate event before or after. If you want help on writing stream classes, have a look at the .Net code itself available at http://referencesource.microsoft.com/netframework.aspx. However, if you want to parse the stream in to something more readable, consider creating an `IEnumerable<MyClass>` that reads in and processes the stream, instead.

Comment: How will I call the base methods if they are abstract?

Comment: @TonoNam What are you reading the data from? If you are reading them from a file, override a `FileStream`. If you are reading form memory, use a `MemoryStream` and so on. If you are unsure, start with a `MemoryStream`.

Comment: the dll method that I am calling comresses a stream and places the output in a different stream so it takes two streams as parameters. I will like to use the 7z.dll because it has the highest compresion ratio for the files I am planing to send. so as the file is being comresed on one stream the output is being writen to a different stream. because i will like to send that output on the netwok i used a networkstream. the problem with that stream is that it does not suport seeking. I know I can compress the file to disk the send it but that is not too efficient...

Comment: I am not familiar with 7z.dll but can you ask the library for the next N bytes data (for Read) or compress the next N bytes of data (for Write)? It so, just call those methods. Otherwise, do them in pages.

Comment: @TonoNam, I strongly recommend to implement working code first even if you think it is "not too efficient". You just for some personal reasons think that if you have whole file in memory code would work faster... it may, but there is a good chance it will not. I.e. if stream need to be seekable because one will always seek to the beginning to update some table there you'll have to keep whole stream in memory all the time... and you'll not be able to send ANYTHING till write completed as you'll not know when seek will happen...

Comment: I am not trying to place the whole file in memory. The file that I need to send over the network is 4GB in size. I don't want to wait 30 min to wait for it to be compress then start sending it. Also I will prefer to use 7zip because it has a higher compression ratio for the files I am trying to send. If you read this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12328068/7zip-compress-network-stream you might understand better what I am trying to do. Maybe I did not explain my self clearly. Anyways thanks for the help! your ans helped me a lot!