# Deserialize non-standard JSON-like format in C#

Tags: c#, json, sql-server

I am trying to deserialize a file containing structured data with C# to export to CSV and insert into an MSSQL Database in the end.

The file looks a bit like JSON but only the **individual lines** are valid JSON.
Example:

```
{"field1": "value1", "field2": "value2", "field3": "value3"}
{"field1": "value4", "field2": "value5", "field3": "value6"}
{"field1": "value7", "field2": "value8", "field3": "value9"}
```

I tried to use Newtonsoft.Json looping over the individual lines but the execution takes a very long time this way as the file given to me is very large (multiple million lines).

Alternativley I tried making this entire thing valid json altering the string using a StringBuilder but that results in loading this entire file into RAM at once which does not seem to be a reasonable option at all.

I even thought about splitting the file into chucks which are then processed concurrently but I assume there must be a cleaner option to do this?

Is this a format that is in some way standardized? What would be the smartest way to go about importing this? Should I skip the CSV and use C# to directly insert the data into the datebase?

Any help appreciated!

Comment: You can look into bulk copy to speed up the database operations. I've used this technique in the past and it works well. Here's a link to get you started: http://richorama.github.io/2017/11/28/sql-bulk-copy/  However, I would probably look at getting this file to the server and doing all the operations in a stored procedure. That would probably give you the best performance.

Comment: @dcp Thank you, this is what I went with, I just converted the lines to a DataTable and handed that over to the bulk insertion which is insanely fast.

Answer (score 2):

Given the size of the file, I'd be tempted to create a custom stream (see [Implement custom stream](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12328623/implement-custom-stream)) that wraps the real file stream such that the first few bytes returned were "{items: [", after that the bytes for the real stream and at the end "]}". That would mean you could use your Newtonsoft.JSON library without trying to build the entire corrected JSON in memory.